# Why does assigning S bring up a patching dialog?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I have a bbappend `openssh_%.bbappend` which has some lines

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"
SRC_URI += "\
    file://custom-ssh/my-special-dir/usr/bin/ssh-custom-bin \
"
```

This addition to the SRC_URI variable causes path rejects inexplicabley. If I remove the SRC_URI addition, then I don't have to manually choose patches when I build my project.

Why is this happening?

Update:

It actually was't the SRC_URI addition. It was another line that read

```
S="${WORKDIR}"
```

I've changed the title of the question to reflect this. I'm still curious why this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S=WORKDIR changes the location of the sources to where the sources are not, so you'll get patch failures because they can't be applied.